# Adding persistence units during run-time

Tags: database, datanucleus

Say you have an application where at some point a user can pull data in to memory from some data store, but you would like to allow users to add the data sources during run time. Could you provide this feature using data nucleus? It seems like data nucleus only lets you add data sources during design time with the persistence.xml file. Is there a way to add a persistence unit during run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you haven't read the documentation, at the foot of the this page
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/persistence_unit.html

Comment: Found it in the docs after I posted this question, couldn't find a similar answer on stack overflow. Thank you.